# Contacts app on Tablet with ICS

Tags: contacts, tablet

I have a Scroll Extreme tablet running 4.0 ICS. Previously I had a Samsung Galaxy SII which had a great Contacts app integrating contacts from MS Exchange, Gmail, Facebook and LinkedIn. How do I make the Contacts app on my tablet visible so I can add contacts or even just check a phone number or address?

Comment: Seems to be the same issue here: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/23735/where-are-my-gmail-contacts